# Unable to execute a foreign key in MySQL 5.5 (using XAMPP)

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-5.5

I am unable to execute a foreign key in MySQL 5.5 (using XAMPP).
Here is the code I am trying to execute:

```
create table Category (
    Category_ID int,
    CategoryName varchar(50),
    Primary Key (Category_ID)
);


create table SubCategory (
    SubCategory_ID int,
    Category_ID int,
    SubCategoryName varchar(50),
    Primary Key (SubCategory_ID),
    Foreign Key Category_ID references Category(Category_ID)
);
```

I tried replacing int with int(10) but it did not help.

Also, I tried adding ON CASCADE suff but it did not work.

Even adding CONSTRAINT inside and outside the table did not work.

Error I keep on getting is:

**1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'references Category(Category_ID))'**

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to wrap your foreign key with parenthesis like:

```
create table SubCategory (
    SubCategory_ID int,
    Category_ID int,
    SubCategoryName varchar(50),
    Primary Key (SubCategory_ID),
    Foreign Key (Category_ID) references Category(Category_ID)
    ------------^-----------^
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much mamdouh alramadan.
I wonder why MySQL cannot say so more clearly.

Compilers like Java, C/C++ and any other programming language are much better than MySQL in this respect.

Comment: it's a valid argument, even though, you need to learn that whenever Mysql says it is near something, take a step back and see what's wrong in the previous command